# Tensorflow performance: there is a long period of idle GPU time in tensorflow timeline

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

There is a long period of idle GPU time in tensorflow timeline as follows:
[image]

The GPU is only used by the model training process, not shared with other process.
The system version is Linux 3.10.0, tensorflow version 1.15, and python version 3.6.8.

Anyone knows what caused the idle time or how to debug?

Comment: One reason could be you data pipeline being bottleneck for model training. If you are using tensorflow try to use `tf.data` from tensorflow for efficient data pipeline

Comment: @ShubhamShaswat, thx for your advice. The speed of reading data is 25 steps/s, while training speed is 4 steps/s. So I think data pipeline is not the bottleneck.